nopcommerce appsettings.json file mission after publish
after publish nopcommerce project then missing appsettings.json. in development mode it's App_data as hiden file but after publish it's missing, so how can i change after publish file.

Yes, After published nop.web

appSettings.json
plugin.json

doesn't copy under app_data. You have to manually copy and paste to published code.
Just For Note
If you still want to appsettings.json and plugin.json file in app_data folder after publish.

Open your project in visual studio 2022
Go to appsettings.json file
Right click and go to properties
Set BuildAction to None
And Set Copy to Output Directory to Copy always
Rebuild your project
Publish again

